# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'vld.lib'

Tags: cmake, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to install VLD visual Link Detector in a CMake project.
The CMake looks like this,

```
find_library(VLD vld HINTS "C:/Program Files (x86)/Visual Leak Detector/lib/Win64/")
find_file(VLD_H vld.h HINTS "C:/Program Files (x86)/Visual Leak Detector/include")
if(VLD_H)
  include_directories(${VLD_H})
  link_directories(${_Visual_Leak_Detector}/lib/Win64/)
  link_libraries(${VLD})
endif()
message("Enabling Visual Leak Detector Done")
```

CMake generation is successful but on building the project, the error is `fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'vld.lib'`
Any suggestions to fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have file `vld.lib` (exactly with that extension) under directory `C:/Program Files (x86)/Visual Leak Detector/lib/Win64/`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes, the file is located at correct location

Comment: What is value of variable `VLD` after `find_library` call? You could print that value e.g. with `message(STATUS "VLD: ${VLD})` or look for it in the cache (file `CMakeCache.txt` in the build directory). Could you show your complete code (in form of [mcve])? The code you currently show just adds library for link with, so it should be following `add_executable` or `add_library` call which creates a target which is actually linked with the library.

Comment: @Tsyvarev apologies for delayed response, I was able to fix the issue with not finding vld.lib but it doesn't show the memory leaks from the code rather the line number